# why isnt the while loop working in this code?

Tags: c, while-loop

so im getting an error message using the while loop and i cant figure out why. it says it expects a ')' before 'matrix' . im new to this so its probably an easy fix. The idea is to repeat the scanf till the matrix is filled with '10'. here is the code:

```
int main()
{int matrix [3][3];
int xd;
int yd;



matrix [0][0]=0;
matrix [0][1]=0;
matrix [0][2]=0;
matrix [1][0]=1;
matrix [1][1]=1;
matrix [1][2]=0;
matrix [2][0]=0;
matrix [2][1]=0;
matrix [2][2]=0;

while
    (matrix [0][0]!=0
matrix [0][1]!=10
matrix [0][2]!=10
matrix [1][0]!=10
matrix [1][1]!=10
matrix [1][2]!=10
matrix [2][0]!=10
matrix [2][1]!=10
matrix [2][2]!=10
){
 printf("coordenadas de disparo x \n");
 scanf("%d",&xd);
 printf("coordenadas de disparo y \n");
 scanf("%d",&yd);
 printf(" coordenadas %d %d \n" , xd, yd);
    /*ja usada*/
 if (matrix [xd][yd] == 10)
    {printf("invalido");}
    /*agua*/
 if (matrix [xd][yd] == 0)
    {printf("-");
    /*acerta*/
    matrix [xd][yd] = 10 ;}
 else printf("%d", matrix [xd][yd]);
  matrix [xd][yd] = 10;}



}
```

Comment: You need a logical operator between each condition. Like `&&` or `||`. Otherwise how else can the compiler know what logic you intend?

Comment: I suggest you replace that long `while` condition with a call to a function. The function can use a loop to test all the elements of the array, rather than listing all the indexes explicitly.

Comment: OT: Using unvalidated input such as `xd` and `xy` is a recipe for disaster. Always check the return value of all functions such as `scanf` and always validate that the parsed value is within the required range.

Comment: Why is the first check for `0` and the rest are for `10`? I thought you want to repeat until all are 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you need to add logical operators between your conditions.

So the code would look like this for the **or** operator.

```
while
(matrix [0][0]!=0 ||
matrix [0][1]!=10 ||
matrix [0][2]!=10 ||
matrix [1][0]!=10 ||
matrix [1][1]!=10 ||
matrix [1][2]!=10 ||
matrix [2][0]!=10 ||
matrix [2][1]!=10 ||
matrix [2][2]!=10 
){

//...code

}
```

And it would look like this for the **and** operator.

```
while 
(matrix [0][0]!=0 &&
matrix [0][1]!=10 &&
matrix [0][2]!=10 &&
matrix [1][0]!=10 &&
matrix [1][1]!=10 &&
matrix [1][2]!=10 &&
matrix [2][0]!=10 &&
matrix [2][1]!=10 &&
matrix [2][2]!=10
){

//...code

}
```

Comment: but after it ends it doesnt ask me again the scanf, any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Well scanf() is inside the loop, so when it ends it doesn't get called. You'll have to put it outside the loop if you want it to get called after the loop.